# How to display SMS conversations effectively in website?

Tags: messages, sms

I have a web application for managing tuition which sends SMS time to time based on user actions. For example when a teacher cancel the class then SMS notification will be send to all the students in this class. All the SMS send from the website is stored in a table.

Now I need to display the SMS in a conversation way. I want to know the best way to display the messages in the website. I am thinking about displaying them like in Smart Phones. But sometimes when I message can repeat when a teacher send a message to many students. So I am confused on how well this can be displayed. Is it better to select the contact first then display between the contacts? Please provide me some thoughts to come up with better UI design for this scenario.

Comment: Google mail are organized into conversations, perhaps that can give you some inspirations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying text messages on a website, then they should look somewhat similar to the way the look on the phone (by that I mean, bubbles(boxes) on the left, same thing on the right, so that the user can feel familiar with the interface right away. Most messaging or email services group messages by conversation, you click on a conversation, then see all the messages that were exchanged in that conversation, any change in that would be massively distracting, so you should stick to that convention.